# xslt remove white space around specific elements (xml to xml)

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a lot of XML files where an export from a database has added certain whitespace via indentation that now I wish to remove in an XSLT 3.0 transformation to a new xml output. I want to remove the whitespace introduced by the export around `<lb>` and `<pb>` (in the original files, before export, these two elements abutted other elements without whitespace - a hidden bug in the export indented them).

This is an example of the problem file to transform:

```
<p xml:id="MS609-0783-LA" xml:lang="LA">
       <seg type="dep_event" xml:id="MS609-0783-1">
          <pb n="58r"/>
          <lb n="1"/>Item. 
          <date type="deposition_date" when="1245-07-07">Anno Domini M°CC°XL°V° Nonas Iulii</date><persName
            nymRef="#ber_r_baz-hg" role="dep">Ber. R.</persName> testis juratus dixit quod vidit
        <persName nymRef="#heretics_in_public" ref="her">hereticos</persName>.</seg>
</p>
```

Here, an example of the desired XML output:

```
<p xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="MS609-0783-LA" xml:lang="LA">
    <seg type="dep_event" xml:id="MS609-0783-1"><pb n="58r"/><lb n="1"/>Item. 
        <date type="deposition_date" when="1245-07-07">Anno Domini M°CC°XL°V° Nonas Iulii</date> <persName
            nymRef="#ber_r_baz-hg" role="dep">Ber. R.</persName> testis juratus dixit quod vidit
        <persName nymRef="#heretics_in_public" ref="her">hereticos</persName>.</seg>
</p>
```

I thought, naively, that I could target it so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
 
   <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.) = '']">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="./following-sibling::tei:pb">
               <xsl:text/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="./following-sibling::tei:lb">
               <xsl:text/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it does not produce the desired result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMpi

Ideally, I am working towards a solution that strips out *any* blank white space out before or after `<pb>` and/or `<lb>` (when they are abutted by other elements), anywhere inside `<seg>` or its descendants.

Many thanks in advance for pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a clear understanding on which text nodes you want to strip but

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:seg//text()[not(normalize-space())][following-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:pb | self::tei:lb]]"/>
```

would strip white-space only ones followed by `pb` or `lb` inside of a `seg`.

Of course you can extend that to the ones preceded by those elements with e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:seg//text()[not(normalize-space())][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:pb | self::tei:lb] or following-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:pb | self::tei:lb]]"/>
```

If the simple blocking based on match patterns doesn't suffice you might want to try whether your definition of "abutted" can be somehow expressed with `group-adjacent` and `xsl:for-each-group` and then drop any white space nodes in a group e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:seg[tei:pb | tei:lb] | tei:seg//*[tei:pb | tei:lb]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::text()[not(normalize-space())]|self::tei:pb|self::tei:lb)">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[self::tei:pb|self::tei:lb]">
               <xsl:sequence select="current-group()[not(self::text())]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: That has the unwanted side-effect of removing whitespace between other elements, like `<date>` and `<persName>`, etc.

Comment: @jbrehr, see whether the edit helps, although it admittedly only tries to move the conditions you had to match patterns. If it doesn't suffice or helps perhaps explain in more detail which kind of white space has to be removed.

Comment: @jbrehr, I have also tried to express "abutted" nodes through `group-adjacent` and `for-each-group`, perhaps that is also an approach to gain control of your requirements.

Comment: Per my post, I simply wanted to "to remove the whitespace introduced by the export around `<lb>` and `<pb>`". (In real terms, this whitespace was only introduced when `<lb>`or `<pb>` were immediately before or after other elements). Looking at your first two examples, I see how the xpath should select and do the job. Yet, it doesn't seem to, for example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMpi/3 . Unless I've missed something....

Comment: Well, the code snippets assume your input elements are in a namespace, as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMpi/4. Perhaps I got confused and assumed that both input and output are TEI documents, if the input has elements in no namespace then you need to use all those match patterns without the use of a prefix e.g.  `  <xsl:template match="seg//text()[not(normalize-space())][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::pb | self:::lb] or following-sibling::node()[1][self::pb | self::lb]]"/>`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my fault: I forgot to add the namespace back in for the TEI fragment...looks just right now, thank you!